# JavaScript button that deletes child object

Tags: apex, javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I have a requirement for a button that will delete a child object based on a query. there are 2 objects, event and enrollment. enrollment has a lookup against event. We need a button on the event that will delete the enrollment where the event is on the current page and the user is the enrolled user on the enrollment. I don't believe the query is returning any results for some reason.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("Select ID, name From SFDC_Enrollment__c Where  Event__c=     '{!SFDC_Event__c.Id}' AND Enrolled_User__c = '{!$User.Id}'", {
  onSuccess : success,
  onFailure : failure
});

  function success(result) {
var records = result.getArray("records");

for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
  var record = records[i];
  sforce.connection.deleteIds(record.Id);
  window.location.reload(); 
    }
  }

  function failure(error) {
  alert('You cannot unenroll for: '+ '{!SFDC_Event__c.Name}' + '. You are not currently enrolled in this event.'); 
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're passing a single Id string to `deleteIds`, when it's expecting an array of Ids. You should build an array of Id's in the loop, and pass it to `deleteIds` in a single call before calling window reload. Like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("Select ID, name From SFDC_Enrollment__c Where Event__c = '{!SFDC_Event__c.Id}' AND Enrolled_User__c = '{!$User.Id}'", {
  onSuccess : success,
  onFailure : failure
});

function success(result) {
  var records = result.getArray("records");
  var idsForDeletion = [];

  for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
      idsForDeletion.push(records[i].Id);
  }

  sforce.connection.deleteIds(idsForDeletion);
  window.location.reload(); 
}

function failure(error) {
  alert('You cannot unenroll for: '+ '{!SFDC_Event__c.Name}' + '. You are not currently enrolled in this event.'); 
}
```